# Why isnt Jest / Enzyme tracking/hearing componentDidMount or any React functions properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have written a function that successfully tests when componentDidMount has fired.
But for some reason using the same logic to test if its neighbouring method has been fired isn't working. Not sure why? Can anyone tell me what i'm misunderstanding?

// Account.js

```
...
componentDidMount() {
    this.checkData();
  }

checkData = () => {
   console.log('i am a check data method that needs testing');
  }
...
```

// Jest

```
// this works
  it('should call the CDM function', () => {
    const instance = mountedComponent.instance();
    jest.spyOn(instance, 'componentDidMount');
    instance.componentDidMount();
    expect(instance.componentDidMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  })

// Attempt 1 - this fails "Cannot spy the checkData property because it is not a function; undefined given instead"

  it('should call the `checkData` function', () => {
    const instance = mountedComponent.instance();
    jest.spyOn(instance, 'checkData');
    instance.componentDidMount();
    expect(instance.checkData).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  })

// Attempt 2 - also fails "Received number of calls: 0"

  it('should call the `checkData` function', () => {
    const instance = mountedComponent.instance();
    instance.checkData = jest.fn();
    instance.componentDidMount();
    expect(instance.checkData).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  })
```

why would CDM be there in the instance but not `checkData` ?>

Comment: You can't spyOn a method AFTER it has been called and expect to see any calls to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the best way to do this is to examine the result and not the function call specifically.

What is `checkData` actually doing (you haven't shown). Is it calling something in another file?

If so, mock the function in the other file to return some data and verify that the mocked function was called when you mount your component.

For example:

```
// component file
import { someMethod } from 'someModule';

export class MyComponent extends React.Component {

   async checkData() {
       await someMethod();
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      this.checkData();
   }

   render() {

   }
}
```

```
// in your spec file
import { someMethod } from 'someModule';

jest.mock('someModule');


someMethod.mockImplementation(() => {
  // do whatever you want here
});

// do your all your normal setup, probably something like this
let mountedComponent;
beforeEach(() => {
  mountedComponent = mount(...);
});

// clear the mock after each mount
afterEach(() => someMethod.mockClear());

it('should do things',() => {
   expect(someMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```